# Add default value on a field while modifying existing elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I've an elasticsearch index with around 10M documents on it. Now I need to add a new filed with a default value e.g `is_hotel_type=0` for each and every ES document. Later I'll update as per my requirments.

To do that I've modified myindex with a PUT request like below-

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "rp": {
      "properties": {
        "is_hotel_type": {
          "type": "integer" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then run a painless script query with POST to update all the existing documents with the value `is_hotel_type=0`

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.is_hotel_type = 0;"
}
```

But this process is very time consuming for a large index with 10M documents. Usually we can set default values on SQL while creating new columns. So my question-
Is there any way in **Elasticsearch** so I can add a new field with a default value.I've tried below PUT request with `null_value` but it doesn't work for.

```
PUT myindex/_mapping/rp
{
  "properties": {
        "is_hotel_type": {
          "type": "integer",
           "null_value" : 0 
        }
      }
}
```

**I just want to know is there any other way to do that without the *script* query?**

Comment: this is a very good question. Very similar to this question was asked by someone else a week ago .. basically that poster wanted to `reindex` and run the `reindex` through the second `mappings` that has this default field. Very interesting. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889629/adding-default-value-to-existing-mapping-in-elastic-search/56890777#56890777